# cap uses admin instead of ec2-user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I'm trying to do a "cap ec2onrails:setup" for my ROR website to an EC2 instance (Amazon image) but authentication keeps asking me for a password no matter what I do. I've tried almost anything I've read in this and/or other forums:

- copy public key from ~/.ssh to ec2-user@_.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys2 (or authorized_keys)
- generate private key using Amazon Management Console and then copying the public key from the server to my machine
- adding any of these keys using ssh-add -l
- generating new keys using ssh-keychain
- using the public/private set of keys already in my machine (id_rsa & id_rsa.pub)
- naming the keys following the above ^^ convention
- chmod 400 for the keys in ~/.ssh
- moving the keys to ~/.ec2
- setting environment vars like stated [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/2007-08-29/GettingStartedGuide/running-an-instance.html)

Notes:

- Connecting to the server using ssh and the AWS .pem key works just
  fine
- It doesn't matter how I set the "keys" value in "ssh_options",
  Capistrano always seems to ignore it. However, it doesn't ignore the
  keys listed in ssh-add -l

Here's how I try to set the key path

```
set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["/Users/dalef/.ssh/pk"]}
```

Here's the output code from my latest test, using verbose output

```
Damians-MacBook-Pro:test dalef$ cap ec2onrails:setup
[Deprecation Warning] This API has changed, please hook `deploy:create_symlink` instead of `deploy:symlink`.
  * 2013-03-20 20:10:52 executing `ec2onrails:setup'
  * 2013-03-20 20:10:52 executing `ec2onrails:server:update_hostname'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' /usr/local/ec2onrails/bin/update_hostname"
    servers: ["___.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.471872 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[3fe825c3c40c]: establishing connection to ___.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.539934 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[3fe825c3c40c]: connection established
I, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.540236 #2647]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3fe825c45728]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.591866 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3fe825c45728]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3'
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.591965 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3fe825c45728]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.6.6 x86_64-darwin12.2.0'
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.635419 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: read 784 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.635555 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 780
I, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.635654 #2647]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fe825c484dc]: got KEXINIT from server
I, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.635844 #2647]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fe825c484dc]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.636042 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 1620
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.636141 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: sent 1624 bytes
I, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.636196 #2647]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fe825c484dc]: negotiating algorithms
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.636319 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fe825c484dc]: negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
* host_key: ssh-rsa
* encryption_server: aes128-cbc
* encryption_client: aes128-cbc
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client: 
* language_server: 
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.636373 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fe825c484dc]: exchanging keys
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.636563 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: queueing packet nr 1 type 34 len 20
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.636613 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.738438 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: read 152 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.738637 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 148
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.744324 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: queueing packet nr 2 type 32 len 140
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.744468 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: sent 144 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.790733 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: read 720 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.790938 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: received packet nr 2 type 33 len 700
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.795329 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: queueing packet nr 3 type 21 len 20
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.795447 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.795542 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: received packet nr 3 type 21 len 12
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.795871 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fe826273f28]: beginning authentication of `admin'
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.796008 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: queueing packet nr 4 type 5 len 28
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.796071 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.944233 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: read 52 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.944626 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: received packet nr 4 type 6 len 28
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.945125 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fe826273f28]: trying publickey
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.945906 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fe826263a88]: connecting to ssh-agent
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.946221 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fe826263a88]: sending agent request 1 len 51
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.946460 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fe826263a88]: received agent packet 2 len 5
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.946578 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fe826263a88]: sending agent request 11 len 0
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.946859 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fe826263a88]: received agent packet 12 len 294
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.947478 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.publickey[3fe826263fd8]: trying publickey (b7:96:23:2d:21:f3:5e:dd:ba:e9:7c:7d:f5:4c:fd:0c)
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.947821 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 348
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.947994 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: sent 372 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.993286 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: read 52 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.993497 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 28
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.993717 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fe826273f28]: allowed methods: publickey
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.993904 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.publickey[3fe826263fd8]: trying publickey (40:2c:20:e7:0c:f4:65:32:76:7c:39:5e:83:84:70:b2)
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.994095 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: queueing packet nr 6 type 50 len 348
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:52.994202 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: sent 372 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:53.035308 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: read 52 bytes
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:53.035556 #2647] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fe825c40570]: received packet nr 6 type 51 len 28
D, [2013-03-20T20:10:53.035693 #2647] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fe826273f28]: allowed methods: publickey
E, [2013-03-20T20:10:53.035782 #2647] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fe826273f28]: all authorization methods failed (tried publickey)
Password:
```

Here's my list of keys for this latest test (just the one I retrieved from the server)

```
Damians-MacBook-Pro:test dalef$ ssh-add -l
2048 b7:96:23:2d:21:f3:5e:dd:ba:e9:7c:7d:f5:4c:fd:0c pk (RSA)
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I'm this close to trying password based authentication.

Thanks!!

**Update**

Still trying alternatives. I've also made sure I'm using the right key by comparing against AWS key fingerprint & authorized_keys

```
From Amazon:
dalef 90:04:34:df:75:cc:9c:f0:90:4f:77:17:98:ee:ec:c1:95:d9:f6:14

Damians-MacBook-Pro:.ssh dalef$ ec2-fingerprint-key dalef
90:04:34:df:75:cc:9c:f0:90:4f:77:17:98:ee:ec:c1:95:d9:f6:14
Damians-MacBook-Pro:.ssh dalef$ ssh-add dalef
Identity added: dalef (dalef)
Damians-MacBook-Pro:.ssh dalef$ ssh-add -l
2048 40:2c:20:e7:0c:f4:65:32:76:7c:39:5e:83:84:70:b2 id_rsa (RSA)
2048 e6:02:1a:a4:2a:f9:63:4a:b7:de:66:60:f2:fa:0c:b4 dalef (RSA)


[ec2-user@___ .ssh]$ cat authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCcfgMIAbEfNAiSgi4zXsObR1zGPHzVbff2suB/J2rLVgr5XNfLhf+kTRzTij0IWsutYj45j/eI87xC912WYtNG2An8262JwqRJZfwbnfDHMjwPQRwlDNjgGWRZwl8x9HO1V7EmBCaEEpeXg0ogbdhM386f/TTdWdUOofSqTEjuN2Nk73OHirPAj7MuWSGwGAwKCS4In2KbGAP/hk0c/PsCx52J+zjp2lteEaA9qWIovQggRw73dAqV++czMwCx2+7GMGxGx21fgSH4cYZ7Q6XxAxBkmsO7yoKZHUFj5QobSJ1TVh7N/61bFInt6Ua6btTXC7jwaATzkOBkv/rwLgtN **dalef**
```

Still asks for password.

**Update**
Something must be really wrong with my setup. I tried allowing password connections but that doesn't work either. Do I need to start thinking of a Capistrano-alternative?

Here's the log

```
[ec2-user@___ ~]$ sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
PasswordAuthentication yes
[ec2-user@___ ~]$ sudo passwd ec2-user
Changing password for user ec2-user.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[ec2-user@___ ~]$ exit
...
E, [2013-03-21T00:31:02.582111 #3739] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fd0f6e21178]: all authorization methods failed (tried password)
connection failed for: admin@___.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: admin)
```

**From these logs what I assume is that Capistrano is trying to login as admin. How can I change that to ec2-user?** (I've tried set :user, "ec2-user" in deploy.rb)

Comment: What do you mean when wrote: `moving the keys to ~/.ec2` ? You should put you id_rsa.pub into server:~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: hlegius: some sites talk about using authorized_keys2 (although I believe that is now deprecated). I did try putting my id_rsa.pub into server:~/.ssh/authorized_keys, but that doesn't work either. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you enabled AgentForward in your /etc/ssh/ssh_config ?

Comment: Just tried that but didn't work. Isn't ForwardAgent meant so you can pull from github with another key?

Answer (score 2):

So after a lot of reading, I found the solution. This pointed me in the right direction: https://serverfault.com/questions/55343/cant-get-ssh-public-key-authentication-to-work

The main issue was that I didn't know what I was doing. So anyway if someone is interested in the solution I came up with:

- Somehow Capistrano always uses an admin user, besides the one you setup, so I created one. You can go ahead and follow these steps: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233
- I created my own set of pub/private keys using ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f ec2admin -t dsa
- I copied the ec2admin.pub file to /home/admin/.ssh in the server, by using scp
- I appended the pub contents to the /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys file in the server
- Then it really helped to read the sshd log at: /var/log/secure (YMMV)
- And finally solved three faulty permissions at /home:

  chmod 700 /home/.ssh

  chmod 600 /home/.ssh/*

  chmod 755 /home/admin

And that did the trick. I can now login without a password. Thanks for your help!